# Правила хорошего тона

Tags: веб-программирование, проектирование

Поделитесь, пожалуйста, ссылочками на статьи, желательно на русском языке, в которых описаны правила хорошего написания кода и составления хорошей структуры проекта. Это касается как названий переменных для php и js, названий классов и ID для CSS, грамотное расположение файлов в проекте, создание качественного и правильно работающего autoload на php, грамотная структура баз данных, в конце концов правильные отступы и прочее. Пусть это будут не целые огромные туториалы, но было бы неплохо увидеть практичные советы для создания качественного, большого проекта, который будет постоянно расти. Знаний языка порой не достаточно, чтобы быть хорошим программистом. Я это осознаю, поэтому прошу поделиться опытом профессионалов. Заранее огромное спасибо.

Comment: пара моих ответов на похожие вопросы:

http://hashcode.ru/questions/386157/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-php-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0/386203

http://hashcode.ru/questions/291288/php-%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/291295

в "культуре программирования", кажется, был какой-то зашквар в одном из пунктов, который нельзя воспринимать всерьез, но мне сейчас лень искать и править )

Answer (score 1):

Касательно структуры проекта на PHP нужно копать в сторону MVC:

- http://habrahabr.ru/post/150267/
- http://habrahabr.ru/post/232089/

А вообще все это и немного больше реализовано во фреймворках типа Symfony и Laravel

О качестве кода PHP копать в сторону PSR http://svyatoslav.biz/misc/psr_translation/

P.S. Все это и многое другое описано здесь [PHP the right way](http://getjump.github.io/ru-php-the-right-way/)

Comment: @vtvz_ru, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Маловато будет... Хотелось бы более обширно изучить эту тему